# UWP RichEditBox LoadFromStram method cannot complete execution when we load corrupted .rtf file

Tags: c#, uwp, richeditbox

I created UWP application in which I set minimum and target version to fall creator update. When I want to read corrupted .rtf file then LoadFromStream method cannot complete its execution and cannot throw any exception either.

```
var fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read); 
RichEditBox.Document.LoadFromStream(TextSetOptions.FormatRtf‌​, fileStream); 
fileStream.Dispose();
```

Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Why  **corrupted** .rtf  file? And necessary code snippet please.

Comment: I want to show dialog box when user wants to open corrupted rtf file. But now it is not possible.                                                                               
 Code:                                                                                                     var fileStream =
                    await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);                      
      RichEditBox.Document.LoadFromStream(TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, fileStream);                                                                 
                fileStream.Dispose();

Comment: Did you mean if the .rtf file is a well file you can read it correctly, and if it is corrupted  you want to show a dialog to tell user this file is corrupted? Is it convenient to provide a sample corrupted file to let me have a test on my side?

Comment: yes u got my point. Take any png file and change its type to rtf file.and then check it.